# how to use drawable resource in background

Tags: android, drawable

I try to use `drawable` on the button but it can't work

What should I do?

button_enable.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="#FF0000FF"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#440000FF"/>
</selector>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="input email"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/button_enable"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if(et1.length()>0)
            btn1.setEnabled(true);
        else
            btn1.setEnabled(false);
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
     }
});
```

Comment: Use `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:background`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `android:color="#FF0000FF"` inside the item you need to use `android:drawable`

and you need to create a drawable with the solid background you are aiming for.

So it would be something like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_press" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_press" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_press"  />
```

and the background drawable something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#FF4081"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Why can't `android:color` be written directly in it? If I use `<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#F60"/>` for editText, the font color can be change. And in editText I use `android:textColor="@drawable/edittext_focused"`

Comment: No reason to use this kind of drawable just to change the color.

Comment: Cuz the Android:colour does exactly that. Changes the colour of the text, not the drawable :)

If you want to change the whole widget background you need a drawable filled with a solid colour or a different shape.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong state. These states applied for switchers. To see color effects on your button try to use this one.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#FF0000FF"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#440000FF"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I try to use it but it still can't work.
I want is when editText no any text, button is unable and background is #440000FF.